# How to filter data from a firebase document?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, ionic4

I am accessing data from a firebase document called "prescription", however, I am new to angular and I am not able to come up with a solution to filter the data by (start_date, date_final, patient_name and name_prescription). I am using framework for mobile device ionic4.

HTML =>

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let prescricao of filteredPrescricoes">
      <ng-container *ngIf="prescricao.nome !== ''; else elseTemplate">
        <ion-label> {{ prescricao.nome }} </ion-label>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-template #elseTemplate>
        <ion-label>Prescrição sem nome</ion-label>
      </ng-template>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

TypeScript =>

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.firestoreService
      .getCollection('prescricao')
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribeAll))
      .subscribe(prescricao => {
        this.prescricoes = prescricao;
        this.loading = false;
        this.filteredPrescricoes = this.prescricoes;
      });
  }
```

---

```
public getCollection(coll: string, where?: any): Observable<any[]> {
    if (where) {
      return this._angularFirestore.
        collection(this._collections.getColl(coll),
          ref => ref.where(where.field, '==', where.value)).
        snapshotChanges().pipe(
          map(actions => actions.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data() as any;
            data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return data;
          }))
        );
    } else {
      return this._angularFirestore.
        collection(this._collections.getColl(coll)).
        snapshotChanges().pipe(
          map(actions => actions.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data() as any;
            data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return data;
          }))
        );
    }
  }


    const alert = await this._alertController.create({
      header: 'Filtro',
      cssClass: 'ion-text-center',
      inputs: [
        {
          placeholder: 'Data inicial',
          label: 'Data inicial',
          name: 'data_inicial',
          type: 'date'
        },
        {
          placeholder: 'Data final',
          label: 'Data final',
          name: 'data_final',
          type: 'date'
        },
        {
          placeholder: 'Nome do paciente',
          label: 'Informe o nome do paciente',
          name: 'nome_paciente',
          type: 'text'
        },
        {
          placeholder: 'Nome da prescrição',
          label: 'Informe o nome do prescrição',
          name: 'nome_prescricao',
          type: 'text'
        }
      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Filtrar',
          handler: (data) => {
            if (data.data_inicial
              && data.data_final) {
              const dataInicial = this.datePipe.transform(data.data_inicial, 'dd-MM-yyyy');
              const dataFinal = this.datePipe.transform(data.data_final, 'dd-MM-yyyy');
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    });

    await alert.present();
  }
```

I need him to bring me only the prescriptions with the term within the margin of the initial date until the final date, with the name of the patient specified and the name of the prescription.

Comment: What is `this.firestoreService`?

Comment: Service file where it will fetch data from the document "prescription" ...

Comment: I added the "getCollection" method in the description

Comment: You're already filtering with `ref.where(where.field, '==', where.value)`. I'm not sure I understand the problem. Did you try adding your additional conditions there?